# create rich text html hyperlink that can be pasted

Tags: python, hyperlink, richtext

I want to create a rich text hyperlink out of an url, which is then pasted as working link. In other words I want to create some sort of behaviour like in this example:

1. On stackoverflow copy the tag catgory **python**
2. Paste it in Microsoft Word

The result is a richt text hyperlink in word, which displays **pyhton** and if I click on the hyperlink it opens up the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python

[image: screencapture of richt text hyperlink]

In Javascript this can be done, somehow like described in [1933185](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53004358/1933185)

For pyhton I have found the module [rich](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html) where you can achive this in a terminal, like describe in [real-working-hyperlinks-in-the-terminal-with-rich](https://www.willmcgugan.com/blog/tech/post/real-working-hyperlinks-in-the-terminal-with-rich/). But I think this is the wrong approach for me.

The modules [pyclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyclip/) and [pyperclip](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip) c'ant handle rich-text.

The basic idea is (done in python):

1. Take a Url, like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python
2. Create a hyperlink out of it: `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python">python</a>`
3. Convert this to a rich-text-hyperlink: [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
4. Copy & paste the richt-text-hyperlink

The steps 1 and 2 are clear, but I struggle on step 3 and 4.

**How can I create a rich-text-hyperlink in pyhton which can be pasted?**